# to dlook up function works when entering data by clicking button

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2016

I'm new to VBA and I am a bit stacked with the following issue.
I have an access form which has a subform.
By clicking the button on a form the data is added to subform and subform is refreshed by following code:

```vb
Private Sub add_Click()

'add data to table
CurrentDb.Execute "insert into Daily_inputs_m (date, text) " & _
" Values ('" & Me.date & "','" & Me.text & "')"

'refresh data in list on form
Me.Daily_inputs_m_sub.Form.Requery  
   
End Sub
```

I want the data on the next column to be changed according to a "text" is added to a table. So please help me with this issue.

For example I have a table with three columns "date","text","text_1" and another table with "text" and "text_1"
In the first form there are two textBoxes and a Button "add" where it should be "date" and "text" typed and then after clicking the button "add" the data as "date" and "text" is added to a subform which represents a table.

So I want the column "text_1" would automatically get the data from the second table which matches to "text" column.

for this I should use dlookup function but I don't know how to do it in VBA.

Comment: If the name of the subform is `Daily_inputs_m_sub` then you should just need `Me.Daily_inputs_m_sub.Requery`

Answer (score 0):

I've finally found a solution how to put a dlookup function into VBA Access:

```
Private Sub add_Click()

txt_1 As String

txt_1 = DLookup("[text_1]", "table_2", "text= '" & Forms!Daily_inputs!txt & "'")

'add data to table
CurrentDb.Execute "insert into Daily_inputs_m (date, text, text_1) " & _
" Values ('" & Me.date & "','" & Me.txt & "','" & txt_1 & "')"    

'refresh data in list on form
Me.Daily_inputs_m_sub.Form.Requery    

End Sub
```